# Sortable List Works on fiddle but not on visual studios

Tags: javascript, list, knockout.js

I'm trying to make a list that allows a user to submit issues.
Im using knockout and i can get it to do exactly what i wanted it to do but when i try to debug in microsoft visual studios it does not work they way I want it to. When I debug, the page opens the same as in the fiddle except the "test issue" is missing from the issue list. Also you can type in the add issue text box but when you hit submit it clears and does not add to the issue list

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/rCB9V/

and here is my code

IssueList ( html )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Issue List</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Issuelist.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Issuelistcss.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class='issuelist'>

    <form data-bind="submit:addIssue">
        Add Issue: <input type="text" data-bind='value:issueToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
        <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: issueToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
    </form>

    <p>Your Issues:</p>
    <select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:allIssues, selectedOptions:selectedIssues"> </select>

    <div>
        <button data-bind="click: removeSelected, enable: selectedIssues().length > 0">Remove</button>
        <button data-bind="click: sortIssues, enable: allIssues().length > 1">Sort</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Issuelistcss (CSS)

```
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.issuelist { padding: 1em; background-color: #87CEEB; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.issuelist input { font-family: Arial; }
.issuelist b { font-weight: bold; }
.issuelist p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.issuelist select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.issuelist h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; }
```

Issuelist (Js)

```
var Issuelist = function () {
this.issueToAdd = ko.observable("");
this.allIssues = ko.observableArray(["test"]);
this.selectedIssues = ko.observableArray(["test"]);

this.addIssue = function () {
    if ((this.issueToAdd() != "") && (this.allIssues.indexOf(this.issueToAdd()) < 0))
        this.allIssues.push(this.issueToAdd());
    this.issueToAdd("");
};

this.removeSelected = function () {
    this.allIssues.removeAll(this.selectedIssues());
    this.selectedIssues([]);
};

this.sortIssues = function () {
    this.allIssues.sort();
};
};

ko.applyBindings(new Issuelist());
```

Comment: So when you run without debugger it's fine, but with debugger it breaks?

Comment: When i click debug it opens chrome like it should but when it opens it doesnt have the "test" in the "Your Issue" box, also when i try and add an issue, when i hit submit the box clears and nothing is added

Comment: Have you got any sort of JS bundler in your project?